# Spring Security Oauth Server

Tags: spring-security

I am implementing Authentication Server with Spring boot following the tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-auth-server .
However I am not able to understand one configuration .

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          articles-client-oidc:
            provider: spring
            client-id: articles-client
            client-secret: secret
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
            scope: openid
            client-name: articles-client-oidc
          articles-client-authorization-code:
            provider: spring
            client-id: articles-client
            client-secret: secret
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/authorized"
            scope: articles.read
            client-name: articles-client-authorization-code
        provider:
          spring:
            issuer-uri: http://auth-server:9000
```

What is articles-client-oidc and articles-client-authorization-code ? What does redirect-uri: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/authorized" do ? Can anyone share any better explanation for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`articles-client-oidc` and `articles-client-authorization-code` are [registrationIds](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/core.html#oauth2login-boot-property-mappings). The are arbitrary identifiers you pick in order to differentiate between different client configurations.

`redirect-uri` is where the authorization server should redirect after the user has authorized the client:

- First, the user goes to your app.
- Second, the user is redirected to the authorization server for login and consent.
- Third, the authorization server redirects to `redirect-uri` to execute the remaining authentication steps.

Spring Security has a built-in endpoint to receive the authorization server's response, so `redirect-uri` is typically set to: `{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}`.

I'm assuming that the article is trying to demonstrate custom redirect URIs, which is why the second client uses `http://127.0.0.1:8080/authorized` instead of the built-in Spring Security support.